# How to import get Exchange code from FINVIZ using importxml, when referencing stock code from a google sheet cell

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am unable to get Exchange name NYSE using =SUBSTITUTE(substitute(importxml(D4,H1),"[",""),"]",""), I receive error message "Resource at url not found". Url in D4 is [https://finviz.com/quote.ashx?t="&C12](https://finviz.com/quote.ashx?t=%22&C12), Xpath in H1 is //span[@class='body-table']. However when I change the url to https://finviz.com/quote.ashx?t=A, it correctly display NYSE.
Am I using the correct formula when referencing a cell as part of the url (ie "&C12), or are websites now restricting you from referencing tickers in cell, as this used to work before. I also checked on Marketwatch which is also rejecting this function with an error message of "Imported content is empty".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=REGEXREPLACE(IMPORTXML("https://finviz.com/quote.ashx?t="&A1, 
 "//span[@class='body-table']"), "[\[\]]", )
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the regreplace solution, actually all with and without regreplace or substitute are now working again, as they were previously, on both Finviz and Marketwatch. I guess it was just an internet glitch caused by the downtime a couple of days ago. Thanks for the quick reply. This question can now be closed.